# In my Java program, I get NullPointerException in my HashMap even after initialising and putting values to the HashMap

Tags: java, hashmap, biginteger, short, linkedhashmap

In my Java program, I get NullPointerException in my HashMap even after initialising and putting values to the HashMap.

```
    LinkedHashMap<Short,BigInteger> ft = new LinkedHashMap<Short,BigInteger>(5);

    ft.put( (short) 1, BigInteger.valueOf(A));
    ft.put( (short) 2, BigInteger.valueOf(B));
    System.out.println(ft.isEmpty());
    System.out.println(ft.get((short)1));
    System.out.println(ft.get((short)2));
    System.out.println(ft.containsKey(1));
    System.out.println(ft.containsValue(1));
```

Comment: where is A and B created?

Comment: Can you show the resulting error, please?

Comment: and where does it fail?

Comment: Which line is causing  NullPointerException ?

Comment: the code runs fine for me when I replace A and B with values. I think there is the issue. post the code where A and B is created...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `A` or `B` are of type `Long` (or `Short` or `Integer`) and contain `null`, that explains the exception (since `BigInteger.valueOf()` expects a `long`, and if you pass it some reference numeric type, it unboxes it to a primitive type, which would cause `NullPointerException` if the `Long`/`Integer`/`Short` is `null`).

I tried to replace A and B with non null values and tested your code, and got no exception, so this must be it.

You can reduce your code to :

```
BigInteger.valueOf(A);
BigInteger.valueOf(B);
```

and still get the exception.

Comment: A and B are of type Short

Comment: @007alibabas Well, if either of them contains null, the same explanation would still apply.

Answer (score 0):

It worked fine with me, as long as A and B arent null. If they are null you will get a Nullpointerexception because u cannot get a BigInteger value from null.

Comment: This isn't really an answer. Why might they be getting a NullPointerException?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the code, if is probable that your variables for A or B are a Long type which could be null.

Viz.

```
long A = 10;
Long B = null;

  LinkedHashMap<Short,BigInteger> ft = new LinkedHashMap<Short,BigInteger>(5);

    ft.put( (short) 1, BigInteger.valueOf(A));
    ft.put( (short) 2, BigInteger.valueOf(B));
```

The above would give the error......

The BigInteger.valueOf(...) would then be the reason for the null pointer exception.

Regards
  Norman